# Highcharts percentage without stacking?

Tags: highcharts, percentage, linechart

Is it possible to create a Highcharts chart with splines in percentages, but WITHOUT them stacking?

I would like to display lines in a relative view, but I would like them to be crossing when their percentages changes.

Basically, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/dp6pjeo9/5/

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        pointStart: 2010,
         stacking: 'percent'

    }
},
```

but without the lines 'stacking' behavior. Stacking is really inconvenient for lines because it is hard to tell whether they are 'absolute' values or 'stacked' values.

See here, the top line should be under then the black line in 2010.

[image]

Comment: Of course it's possible. But you'll need to provide a lot more detail about what you actually want to do, what your data is, etc. Best thing to do to get a better answer is work up a fiddle of what you have, and what isn't working the way you want it.

Comment: Ok @jlbriggs. Will do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to process you data before you put them in the chart config.

Calculate sums:

```
var data = [3, 5, 10, 15,25]
var data2 = [25,15, 10, 5, 0]

var sum = data.map((v, i) => v + data2[i]) // grab sums
```

Calculate percentages and set data:

```
    series: [{
    name: 'Installation',
    data: data.map((v, i) => ({
      y: v / sum[i] * 100,
      absoluteY: v
    }))
}, {
    name: 'Manufacturing',
    data: data2.map((v, i) => ({
      y: v / sum[i] * 100,
      absoluteY: v
    }))
}]
```

Change tooltip's pointFormat so it shows absolute y value instead of percentage value

```
tooltip: {
  pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.absoluteY}</b><br/>'
},
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/dp6pjeo9/6/

Comment: Ah thanks, this is also possible of course. I just need to set all the axis formatters etc. etc. Well, better than nothing I guess.

Comment: @RobAu You shouldn't have to do anything to the axis label formats - this solution is going to plot your data as percent values (which will be reflected in the axis labels) - the purpose of the tooltip formatter is to show the *actual* (original) value of the point, if you want to display it. If you *don't* want to show the percent values in the axis labels, then I am not understanding your original quesiton.

Comment: Ah I see, sorry, I misunderstood. Thanks!